How to call a Python script using several modules from a Bash script?
Based on an answer, I've made a Bash script to install the requirements and run a Python script working with a MariaDB database. In WSL, the Python script runs well, but when I run the Bash script from Windows 11 command line, I get following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mariadb'

Unlike another question concerning the same error, I've verified by python3 -V I use Python 3.10 in the whole process. Commenting the MariaDB connector out has shown the same problem with other other imported modules. My Bash, editted:
python3 -m venv "c:\path\to\venv"
"c:\path\to\venv\Scripts\activate"
pip3 install -r "c:/some/path/requirements.txt"
python3 "c:/some/other/path/myscript.py"

The requirements.txt file:
mariadb==1.1.10
datasets
sentence_transformers

EDIT: Thanks to the comments and answers, I've got rid of the following error:
bash: venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory

However, the main problem lasts, it just changed from ImportError to ModuleNotFoundError. All the requirements either install correctly, or report "Requirement already satisfied".

bash: venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory. error says that you dont have that file.
try to check it manually if not there, may try to create the virtual environment manually.

So did python3 -m venv venv fail? You can use set -e to force Bash to exit when a command fails, or python -m venv venv || exit to explicitly exit if this fails.

@HenroSutrisnoTanjung I've used the same command as in the WSL. Probably, I must install Docker outside WSL too to make it work. Thanks for a hint!

If you are on Windows (command line or bash), the installation layout is different from *nix.
activate is a batch file and stored under venv/scripts.
See also: How venvs work

Solved! Ruwan's note #add path if have pushed me to analyze the requirement.txt call deeper. That's how I've found the solution. I changed the line to:
python3 -m pip install -r "c:/some/path/requirements.txt"

The pip3 was linked to another version of Python (3.8 in my case). python3 -m tied it to the right one.

well, Happy to help you somehow. :)

I think problem is how you are trying to activate the environment, It should activate like this
venv\Scripts\activate

Then you can try to install requirement.txt
pip install -r requirement.txt #add path if have


No, that's not correct for Bash; you need to source the activate script, and backslashes are not acceptable as directory separators.

You need
source "c:\path\to\venv\Scripts\activate"

to activate the virtual environment from bash.
